# Creating a new TextView programmatically in a public class

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-widget

I am newbie to Android, apology if my question is so stupid!

I created a new TextView in a public class, but then when I wanted to assign ID to it, [ I tried text1.setID(1) ], but Eclipse not recognize text1.

What is the problem? Did I define TextView wrong?

Actually my goal is that to create a class (here Class Post) which include 2 textViews(text1 & text2), then I want to create object from this class in my program( ex. in main activity), is this a right way to do it? ( a kind of simply creating new android widget)

```
public class Post{

Context Creator_Context;
public Post(Context context)
 {
    ctx= context;
 }

//Creating a textview.

TextView text1 = new TextView(Ctx);
TextView text2 = new TextView(Ctx);


///////here is the PROBLEM////// :

text1.setID(1);

}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting tag for the textView that you have created. (Tag can be an alphanumeric string)

```
textView.setTag("TAG-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you need to follow to create a simple widget.

Instead of that, a more simple way would be to extend an existing component and to put your textview inside. For instance you could extend FrameLayout :

```
public class TwoLinesTextButton extends FrameLayout {

private TextView textView1;
private TextView textView2;

public TwoLinesTextButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView(context, attrs);
}

public TwoLinesTextButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initView(context, attrs);
}


public void fill(String text1, String text2) {
    textView1.setText(text1);
    textView2.setText(text2);
}

private void initView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = infl.inflate(getLayoutResource(), null);


    textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
    textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_2);

    this.addView(view);
}


protected int getLayoutResource() {
    return R.layout.twolinestextbutton;
}
```

}

and in layout/twolinestextbutton.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"/>
```

Comment: See the example i have posted, I creates a component that has two TextView one below the other

Comment: This makes a kind of widget that use can use in your code or in a layout.xml file